# Does including an entire namespace slow things down?

Tags: c#

Is there any evidence that suggests including a whole namespace in c# slows things down?

Is it better to do this

```
System.IO.Path.Combine....
```

Or to include the whole System.IO namespace?

Comment: Worst case scenario of `using System.IO`: You have a larger (or conflicting) IntelliSense list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's much better to include the namespace in a `using` statement at the top of your class.  The compiler doesn't care; it will emit the same IL both ways, and your code will be shorter and easier to read.

Comment: This must be a C++ thing, I remember hearing somewhere that including namespaces slows things down. I'm glad this is cleared up :-)

Comment: Could you please provide the IL outputs in your answer?

Comment: So, what about loading assemblies into the AppDomain at runtime? Would the entire namespace be loaded or would just the class be loaded? Also, if just the class is loaded, is only the class loaded when you reference a class in a namespace that is imported in it's entirety or is the entire namespace loaded?

Answer (score 3):

No matter what, including the entire namespace will not slow down production code.

Will it slow down the compiler? That's debatable, but C# compilation is so fast it's unlikely. A far worse offender in slowing down compilation is a large number of projects in your solution.

Comment: "C# compilation is so fast".  Surely, you jest.  I can go and play a full round of ping-pong for some of my larger projects.

Comment: Did I not mention something along the lines of "a far worse offender in slowing down compilation is a large number of projects in your solution"?

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference... it's purely for readability and in cases where you have naming collisions.

Answer (score 1):

It will not slow down your production code, however it could slow down your coding as the IDE has to show you more options and you have to pick through more possibilities when looking at code completion lists.

Answer (score 1):

Adding extra namespaces can affect the compile time of your application.  It's unlikely to be noticable in most applications but extremes could make it visible.

It however has no impact on the runtime performance of your application.

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiler is fast enough. Not sure what else I can add :)