# Using namespace explicitly versus including the whole reference

Tags: c#, meta

In C#, is it more efficient from a memory management perspective to use a typed namespace or to include the whole namespace?

For example:

```
using mySpace.someLogic;

public class Foo
{
 public void Bar()
 {
  doSomethingFromsomeLogic();
 }
}
```

versus

```
public class Foo
{
 public void Bar()
 {
  mySpace.someLogic.doSomething();
 }
}
```

Is one way more efficient? If the answer is "it depends", then what does it depend on?

This question is similar [Does including an entire namespace slow things down?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1746722/1026459), but asks about speed and I am more concerned about memory.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer to the question you linked says "The compiler doesn't care; it will emit the same IL both ways, and your code will be shorter and easier to read."  Identical IL implies no difference in speed; it also implies no difference in memory use.  The `using` directive is not an executable statement.

Comment: @phoog - Thank you, I actually had not realized that until Yuck answered that the references wouldn't be included which made me think about how the .dll is made.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It makes no difference - this is totally personal preference. The compiler will work the same against either style. If, during compilation, it determines you're not using the reference it won't be included.

Related to your question, Visual Studio has tools to clean up and remove unused references.

Answer (score 3):

It slows you down as a programmer, which is more important than slowing the computer down.

It makes no difference in the resulting compiled code, though.